# Programmatic Autolayout changes behaviour of a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a controller where I add a subview programmatically. With the configuration of the subview I add autolayout constraints programmatically. Everthing is working except that the view doesn't react on touches if I add the constraints and even the set backgroundcolor is not displayed.

The buttonView should be displayed in the lower right corner of my parent view.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Here is how I add my constraints:

```
 private func configureAutolayoutConstraints(buttonView: UIView, parentView: UIView){

        buttonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonView, attribute:
            .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -130)

        parentView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)


        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonView, attribute:
            .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -90)
        parentView.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

    }
```

Comment: You need to provide at least 4 constraint to make it work. You have given bottom and trailing only. You need either width+height OR leading+top constraint also.

Comment: exactly! Please write it as an anser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout engine needs at least 4 constraints to determine the frame of view. You have applied bottom and trailing constraints only. You need either `width+height` **OR** `leading+top` constraint to make it work.